# Is there a browser extension for any browser that allows two "finds" in the page with different highlighting colours?

Tags: find, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, highlighting

With most apps including browsers there is a "Find" function for searching for text in the current document. All instances of matching text are highlighted to make them easy to see.

But sometimes you want to search for two different pieces of text. This would be fairly easy for geeks who know regular expressions in apps whose find can handle regular expressions... but browsers' "find" function doesn't usually support regex and it's hard for non-geeks to use.

So I'm wondering if there's a browser extension for Firefox, Chrome, or any other browser which will, for instance, let you "find" one term and highlight it in say yellow, and "find" a second term and highlight it in say bright green.

(I've searched but haven't been able to find one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googlebar Lite](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/googlebarlite/) for Firefox includes such a feature. You can put multiple strings in the search field, click highligt and then see all matches.

[image]